# How to determine the angle range that a box can rotate within an image

Tags: algorithm, geometry, mathematical-optimization

I want to find an algorithm that can find the angle range that a box can rotate around the top-left corner within an image. For example, in the picture below, I can calculate alpha_1 and alpha_2, which is the angle range I wanted.

[image: image 1-a]

[image: image 1-b]

But there are many situations according to the position of top-left corner of the box, e.g., in the image below, I need to calculate the different angles.

[image: image 2-a]

[image: image 2-b]

So my purpose is to find an algorithm to solve this problem. The worst way is using a lot of if-else to calculate the range, but I want a more efficient way to do this.

**EDIT:** Thanks for the idea from @MBo, here is my pseudo code to solve this problem:

```py
box1 = Polygon(*box1_pts)

# Three circles of box2's width, height and diagonal.
box2_wc = Circle(c=top_left_pt, r=box2_w)
box2_hc = Circle(c=top_left_pt, r=box2_h)
box2_dc = Circle(c=top_left_pt, r=box2_d)

# Angle between box2's diagonal and x-axis.
angle_diag = angle(Line(top_left_pt, top_left_pt+box2_size)

# Find three sectors that box2's width, height and diagonal can rotate within box1.
angle_range_w = find_sector(
    points=box1.intersection(box2_wc),
    center=top_left_pt,
).angle_range
angle_range_h = find_sector(
    points=box1.intersection(box2_hc),
    center=top_left_pt,
).angle_range
angle_range_d = find_sector(
    points=box1.intersection(box2_dc),
    center=top_left_pt,
).angle_range

angle_range_h += 90
angle_range_d += angle_diag

angle_range = intersect_angle_range(angle_range_w, angle_range_h, angle_range_d)
```

[image: result]

And here is another related problem, I want to find the red box's free rotation range that the red box can contain the blue one. The top-left corner of the red box is also fixed.

My current idea is to calculate the angles that four edges of red box intersect with the four corners of blue box if applicable, then calculate the intersection angle range same as the above one. I wonder if there is a efficient way just like the above one.

[image: image-3-a]
[image: image-3-b]

Comment: There may be two ranges

Answer (score 0):

ou can use the arctan (inverse tangent) function to calculate the angle between two points. By taking the coordinate values of each point and forming a right triangle, you can determine whether the angle will be narrow or wide based on the positions of the points. The calculation treats it as a narrow angle if it's wide, and it calculates the angle accordingly.
[wide angle calc](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZM5FH.png)

```
def calculate_right_triangle(point1, point2):
    # Calculate triangle sides
    side1 = abs(point2[0] - point1[0])
    side2 = abs(point2[1] - point1[1])
    hypotenuse = math.sqrt(side1**2 + side2**2)

    # Calculate the angles
    if point2[1] > point1[1]:
        first_angle_degrees = math.degrees(math.atan(side1 / side2))
    elif point2[1] < point1[1]:
        first_angle_degrees = 180 - math.degrees(math.atan(side1 / side2))
    else:
        # Handle the case where the points are on the same horizontal line (avoid division by zero)
        first_angle_degrees = 0
    print(f"First angle: {first_angle_degrees} degrees")
    return first_angle_degrees
```

Answer (score 0):

You have three free vertices. Every vertex has set of valid ranges for free rotation and excluded ranges (no rotation possible)

Let small rectangel sides are `a` and `b`, axis position is `cx, cy` relative to large rect bottom left corner, large rect size is `height, width`, starting (zero) angle corresponds to side `a` directed down, side `b` directed right (BTW, it would be nice to describe such setup in the question).

Four outer sides might give some **excluded** angle intervals for side `a`:

```
 if a>cy:   #with bottom side
     intervals += 0..acos(cy/a)
     intervals += 2*pi-acos(cy/a)..2*pi
 if a>width-cx:   #with right side
     intervals += pi/2-acos((width-cx)/a)..pi/2+acos((width-cx)/a)
   similar for upper and left borders
```

Do the same for diagonal (`diag_len=sqrt(a*a+b*b)`) and side `b`, just make correction by angle between diagonal and `a` and by `pi/2` for side `b`

After all join all excluded ranges (like using boolean operation OR), and invert result - now it is the set of free rotation ranges.